# Why duplicate script tags do not produce duplicate requests?

Tags: javascript, http, loading

I have a very simple test case (and 3 hours of googling and a flu)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Два внешних скрипта</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/myscript.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/myscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the server return the following reponse headers

```
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Mon, 04 Dec 1999 21:29:02 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
```

This code executed in chrome produces one request to server, also in opera, safari win.

Is this behaviour in anyway standard?

Is there any official documentation for this behaviour?

Is this cashe issue, cause I thought you will still have a request anyway with 304 response?

Disclaimer: please do not suggest randomizing or avoiding this issue. I want to learn background of this issue

Comment: Why would the browser download the file a second time when it's just put it in its cache?

Comment: There's a difference between caching in the browser and caching on the server

Comment: You should differentiate between "making a call" and loading a resource. Your browser is intelligent enough to know it already has a resource. it does not know that you want to make a call multiple times.

What do you actually want to do? Maybe read a bit about Ajax.

Comment: I think it wont make a second request depending on the value of the `expires` header that came with the first response.

Comment: that is all very good but without proof...documentation and references please?

Comment: Why do you need references when you just confirmed how it works? This might be mentioned in some document, but not every feature is written down, especially when it's not a part of a standard specification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two reasons why this can happen. The first is that the content provider can set the `expires` heading so that the browser will not issue a second request, and the second is how browsers actually handle `GET` requets in HTTP, such as the get request to include the script.

### 1. Setting Expires Header of Content

The content provider can set the `Expires` header so that the script is cached by the browser the first time, hence the lack of a second request. This is a good standard web practice for speeding up web pages, and the expires header is set by the host server of a script. Yahoo Developer has a good article on this at [Add an Expires or a Cache-Control Header](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) which recommends adding the Expires header to scripts and stylesheets in addition to images.

### 2. Script Get Method is Idempotent

`GET` requests, such as the get request to include the javascript on a webpage are safe methods according to the HTTP specification. Safe methods are also idempotent, in that multiple requests yield the same result as a single request and that the method is only used to retrieve data. Many browsers take advantage of this property of the HTTP specification, and won't sent multiple requests for idempotent methods. George Cummins explained this well, and an article on this is available from the [Mozilla Developer Network](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP).

Comment: I've tried
It even happens with the following headers

    Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
    Expires:Mon, 04 Dec 1999 21:29:02 GMT
    Pragma:no-cache

I will add a test snippet if neccessary

Comment: Get requests, such as the get request to include the javascript on a webpage are safe methods according to the HTTP specification. Safe methods are also idempotent, in that multiple requests yield the same result as a single request and that the method is only used to retrieve data. Many browsers take advantage of this property of the HTTP specification, and won't sent multiple requests for idempotent methods. George Cummins explained this well, and an article on this from the Mozilla Developer Network is available here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP

Comment: I have edited the response above to include the above comment for clarification.

Answer (score 5):

Many HTTP methods (GET, HEAD, PUT, DELETE) are defined to be *idempotent* which means that multiple identical requests have the same effect as a single request. Browsers take this into account and will avoid the overhead of sending multiple identical requests where possible.

For more information, see the [Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1 RFC section 9.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.1). For a high-level overview, see the [Wikipedia article on HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Idempotent_methods_and_web_applications).

Comment: Thanks you anwser was very usefull, but I chose another anwser because now it looks more explanatory.